# DataGridView Vertical ScrollBar not drawn on Invalidate()?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, c++-cli, .net-4.5

I have a *virtual* DataGridView (DGV) with Vertical ScrollBar enabled. The DGV is ReadOnly. The event `CellValueNeeded` is correctly handled. At beginning, the row count is less than what can be displayed and the scrollbar is not drawn. That is correct.

In a second thread (Thread... ->Start) I add new rows. Still in this thread, I update `DGV->RowCount` according to the total number of row and call `DGV->Invalidate( true )` with the hope that the scroll bar will be drawn if necessary.

Then I observe a strange behaviour: while `CellValueNeeded` is still correctly called, the *area* of the scrollbar is not invalidated. It appears as a "not redrawn" zone. If I minimize the form then restore it, the scrollbar appears as a black rectangle. It is like if the scroll bar itself had `Visible=false`.

I even tried to put the `DGV->RowCount` between a `DGV->ScrollBars=ScrollBars::None;` and a `DGV->ScrollBars=ScrollBars::Vertical;` then between a `DGV->SuspendLayout()` and a `DGV->ResumeLayout()` but the behaviour remains the same for the two tries.

Many questions:

1. Is `DGV->RowCount` update processed correctly? I do it in the second thread, not in the Main thread because I naively believe that the DGV being purely ReadOnly, it won't cause any conflict. Maybe I'm wrong?
2. Is the Invalidate() (called also in the second thread because it only adds a message in the queue, no?) sufficient to make the scroll bar appear?

I saw a couple of message on the Web about difficulties with the DataGridView scrollbars. Is there a bug with this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

The `DGV->RowCount` cannot be done on the second thread. I guess because the scroll bar would be instantiated on this thread rather than on the main (GUI) thread. This is bad.

So, I wrote a little method like this:

```
void MyClass::UpdateRC( void )
{
    DGV->RowCount = ...;
}
```

then I called it like this from the second thread:

```
Invoke( gcnew MethodInvoker( this, &MyClass::UpdateRC ) );
```

and everything worked fine!

Voilà! I hope this will help all of you who are facing the same problem in the future.